# How do I compile a C++ file that uses both MPI and HDF5?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am creating *.h5 files so I have been compiling with:

```
h5c++ -o output myFile.cpp
```

However, I added MPI to speed up the code in one of the sections. The same compilation gives me an undefined reference error.

```
undefined reference to `MPI_Init'
```

How do I compile the code so that I can use MPI as well as HDF5?

Answer (score 1):

you can tell the HDF5 wrapper to use the MPI wrapper instead of your C++ compiler.
for example, if your MPI wrapper is `mpiCC`, you can simply

```
export HDF5_CXX=mpiCC
export HDF5_CLINKER=mpiCC
```

**[this answer has been edited]**

Comment: This hasn't worked. Is there anything else that I might be missing?

Comment: my bad, you also need `export HDF5_CLINKER=mpiCC`

Answer (score 0):

Both `mpicc`, as well as `h5cc` (and their C++ counterparts), are not compilers, but only wrappers, that only add some flags to the compiler call. These flags typically include linked libraries and include paths. You can actually inspect them!

```bash
$ mpicc --showme    # OpenMPI
$ mpicc -show       # MPICH
$ h5cc  -show
```

So the answer to you question is: Make a compiler call with all flags from both wrappers.

However, typically you should just leave this to a build system like CMake, which will assemble all relevant compiler flags.